# Showing that $e^x=3x$ has exactly 2 solutions in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show, that $e^x=3x$ has exactly 2 solutions in $\mathbb{R}$

Let $f(x) = e^x-3x$. $f$ is oviously  continuous.
Consider $f(0)= e^0-3\cdot 0 = 1 > 0,$ $f(1)= e^1-3\cdot 1 = e-3 < 0$, $f(10) = e^10-3 \cdot 10 >0$
$\Rightarrow$ $f$ has, according to the Intermediate value theorem,  at leat $2$ solutions in $\mathbb{R}$. But how can i show that $f$ has exactly $2$ solutions?

Comment: Hint: $f$ is convex.

Comment: convex has not been defined so far

Comment: Or: $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x\le\log3$ and increasing on $x\ge\log3$, so can have at most one zero in each of these ranges.

Comment: Do you know about derivatives? If it had more solutions the derivative would have two zeros (Rolle's theorem). But the derivative is $e^x-3$, which vanishes only at $x=\ln(3)$.

Comment: If $f(x)=e^x-3x$, and $x>10$ you can see $f'(x)=e^x-3>0$

Answer (score 1):

Usually in these types of problems one uses the Mean Value Theorem (or more specifically Rolle's Theorem) to show that a function can have at most some number of zeroes.

In your case you want to show $f(x) = e^x-3x$ has at most 2 zeroes.  So pretend you have 3, say at $x=a < b < c$.  Use Rolle's theorem to show that $f'$ must have a zero between $a$ and $b$, and a zero between $b$ and $c$.  So $f'$ has at least 2 zeroes.  But using Rolle's theorem again this means $f''$ has a zero.  Now show this is a contradiction...

Comment: Can't i just say, that $f$ can't have an odd number of zeroing, since $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm\infty}e^x-3x= +\infty$? But how to show this for an even number of zeroing?

Comment: @fear.xD No you can't really say that, for example $f(x)=x^2$ has one (an odd number) of zeroes and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Use differentiation: $f'(x)=e^x-3$.  Now if $x<\ln3$ then $f'(x)<0$, so $f(x)$ is always decreasing, so how many times can $f(x)$ equal zero?

Comment: Only two times because it only has  max.  1 Inflection point.

Comment: You mean turning point not inflection point, otherwise fine.  There will be only one solution for $x<\ln3$ and similarly only one for $x>\ln3$.